# Copying Eclipse from one machine to another

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, updates

I am trying to include a version of Eclipse in an installation package, that has been prepopulated with plugins from an update site.

I can include all of Eclipse's files into my installer quite easily but when I run Eclipse on the target machine, the list of update sites is lost. E.g. When I run it on my own machine and select Help/Install new software... the "Work with" list contains the recently used update sites. When I run it on the target machine it is empty.

I have tested just copying my Eclipse folder from a network share onto the target machine and get the same results. However, when I run Eclipse directly from the network share the "Work with" list is populated as I would expect.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely missed the configuration directory that is part of the users' home directory (`${HOME}/.eclipse` for Linux).

Comment: Thanks. I now know what the problem was. Although I still don't understand why running from the network share worked...

Comment: I don't know either, but I would guess that the eclipse binary from the network share has some additional parameter or environment variable (assuming that it worked on the target machine when executed from the network share, without any change on the target machine)...

Comment: I think you are right, there must be additional information available to it.